# How to sum an array in Node.Js for Discord Bot

Tags: javascript

I am a real noob when it comes to everything Node.js or Javascript. I am working on my own discord bot as a way to learn :). I was hoping to get some help to solve my current problem: So say I have a table that shows the amount of hours John and Jane worked this week. So John worked: (Monday, 5)(Tuesday,6)(Wednesday, 6)(Thursday, 5)(Friday, 4). Jill worked: (Monday, 4)(Tuesday,3)(Wednesday, 4)(Thursday, 8)(Friday, 3). Is there a way I can make a command using my discord bot where I can type "John Tuesday Thursday" with the response being "17" (Essentially summing Tuesday through Thursday as opposed to summing just those two days).

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will depend on data structure you use. The simplest approach I can come up with is to store working hours for each day in array for each user.

```
const worked = {
  'John': [5, 6, 6, 5, 4],

  'Jill': [4, 3, 4, 8, 3]
};
```

You will have separate array for weekdays indexes in this case:

```
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
```

So you can call your calculation function like this:

```
sum(worked[user], days.indexOf(from), days.indexOf(to));
```

Implementation is below. You may want to add validation for non-existent user and days as well.

```js
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];

const worked = {
  'John': [5, 6, 6, 5, 4],

  'Jill': [4, 3, 4, 8, 3]
};


function sum(array, fromIndex = 0, toIndex = array.length-1) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i=fromIndex; i<=toIndex; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

const response = sum(worked['John'], days.indexOf('Tuesday'), days.indexOf('Thursday'));
console.log(response);  // 17
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you think you can help me figure this part: 

if(message.content === ""){
    message.channel.send(sum(worked[''], days.indexOf(''), days.indexOf('')))

What can I do with the message.content part so that the bot dynamically knows what values to put in.